# Query by map key that contains a "."

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

With the following document, how would you escape the `where` query ?

```
/posts/abc
   users: [map]
      abc.def: 4
```

```
firestore().collection('posts').where('users.abc.def' , '>' , 0)
```

Is there a way to escape the `.` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kmoser mentioned in the comment above, the solution is to use `FieldPath`

```
firestore().collection('posts').where(new firestore.FieldPath('users', 'abc.def'), '>' , 0)
```